# Meaning of words in a marriage/baby shower invitation

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, terminology, meaning

I recently came across an invitation for baby shower. I have mentioned below some terms mentioned in it on which i wanted some clarification/their meaning.

1. **Dhouhitran** (and there was another word with a similar meaning. Not sure. If anyone knows, please provide the meaning for that too)
2. **Naazhigai**
3. **Pumsavana**
4. **Kanganadharanam**
5. **SwasthiSri**

Comment: Guessing; Kankanadharanam is (time for) gold bangle ornament decoration. SwasthiSri: Auspicious  person or Chiranjeevi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Dhouhitran* is more commonly spelled as *Douhitra* (दौहित्र), and it just means the son of one's daughter. ([Source](https://learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=dauhitra&dir=au))

*Naazhigai* is a Tamil word for 'twenty-four minutes ([Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/VARMAM_AN_INSIGHT_INTO_THE_ANCIENT_SYSTE/GaNBDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=naazhigai&pg=PT23&printsec=frontcover)). It is one unit in a more complex time-counting system. I can't find any uses of it being used in a ceremonial context, but I assume that it has something to do with how long one has to do a certain action.

*Pumsavana* is a ceremony, part of the Shodasha Karma, that is done during a woman's pregnancy, traditionally to secure the birth of a male child. It is typically done when the mother's stomach is starting to become larger and the baby is beginning to show ([Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Yajnavalkya_Smriti/8QcNAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=pumsavana&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover)).

*Kanganadharanam* is, I suspect, a variant of *Kankana Dharanam.* This is a part of the marriage ceremony, during which the bride and groom tie threads of saffron around each other's wrists. ([Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hindu_Manners_Customs_and_Ceremonies/XjLXAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Kankana%20Dharanam&pg=PA224&printsec=frontcover))

*Swasthi*, or 'svasthi,' doesn't have much specific to birth ceremonies, as far as I can tell. But, it has several meanings in Sanskrit, including *well-being, success, prosperity, luck, happiness, fortune, and welfare.* ([Source](https://learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=svasti&dir=au)) 'Sri' was likely added on.

Comment: How can pumsavana be done for male child specifically? It can also be a female child, right?

Comment: @Newbie - pumsavana is traditionally done for having a male child, but there may be an equivalent pooja for having a female child, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Dhouhitran is daughter's son. Poutran is son's son. Both are grandsons. Also heard that Dhouhitran has full authority to do funeral rites for the grandfather/grandmother. Poutran has rights only to hold the oil-lit pyre stick.

Naazhigai is just a unit of time. I think it is equal to 24 minutes. Jamam is another unit of time of 3 hours. The first Jamam of morning is from 3:00 am to 6:00 am and so on.

Comment: Could you add citations?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).